# How can I join Yahoo without giving a phone number?

Tags: yahoo

The last question that was asked about this was in 2013. While looking at the question the site I found that it was pretty outdated. Yahoo has recently made some changes where I cannot go to Yahoo without a phone number. I would like to know is there any way that I can pass this or join Yahoo without one? I want to make a new more professional account.

Comment: You can cheat and use a service like maskme.com, but it's not free. You can also get a Google voice number or something (that forwards to your real phone), or use twilio.com. There are also free trials of forwarding phone numbers.

Comment: What question is that? What makes you think that the answer isn't still the same?

Comment: Because, back in 2013 YA had a different look to it. Now in 2014 they completely changed the Yahoo format and look.

Comment: You still haven't indicated what question it is. If the answers are out of date, the existing answers can be edited or a new answer added. There's no point in having duplicate questions with answers; it just makes the information harder to find.

Answer (score -1):

Haven personally tried it myself, but you could actually try it. Use a "fake" number to "trick" Yahoo.

There are services that provides numbers that can receive SMS online: [link](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/top-10-sites-receive-sms-online-without-phone/)